# Spark job never progresses from ACCEPTED state and hangs with a status of UNDEFINED

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have a simple hadoop cluster consisting of one master node and two slave nodes.  I have installed spark and I am attempting to run the suggested example job from the spark examples:

```
./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
```

It appears as if everything gets submitted to the  correctly and the state of the job is updated to ACCEPTED however it remains with this status.  On inspection of the output I found the following:

```
2018-05-21 16:27:41 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for 
application_1526910547092_0004 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-05-21 16:27:41 INFO  Client:54 - 
 client token: N/A
 diagnostics: [Mon May 21 16:27:40 +0200 2018] Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as cluster resource is empty.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:1024, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:0, vCores:0>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:0, vCores:0>; 
 ApplicationMaster host: N/A
 ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
 queue: default
 start time: 1526912860005
 final status: UNDEFINED
 tracking URL: http://vm-10-155-208-189:8088/proxy/application_1526910547092_0004/
 user: root
```

Specifically the following: Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as cluster resource is empty.  Details : AM Partition = ; AM Resource Request = ; Queue Resource Limit for AM = ; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = ; Queue AM Resource Usage = ;

So it seems to imply that I have a limit of 0 set for available memory and a limit of 0 for vCores?

My machines have 8GB of RAM each and at least 20GB each of free space, so I am not sure why this job never actually gets allocated any resources?

Similarly I am not able to launch the spark-shell, it just forever hangs after the command is entered.

I must have configured something incorrectly but I am not sure what.  In the Hadoop resource manager I can see the jobs, and it shows each machine has enough resources so I do not understand what is causing the problem.

Edit:

Added screenshot from the resource manager.  Does this mean I need to change the  entries to higher numbers?  If so how do I do this?

[image]

Comment: It's looks like all your resources are allocated, so no more jobs can started. Check Spark UI or YARN to see how much resources you have and how they are allocated. Maybe there are hang jobs that doing nothing but lock all your memory/CPU.

Comment: There are as far as I can tell enough resources available.  None of the machines are doing anything and this is the first job I have submitted.  So there is nothing else running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by noticing that in the Hadoop web UI my datanodes were showing as active but in the resource manager no active nodes were displaying.

The problem was fixed by modifying the yarn-site.xml on the namenode and all datanodes to the following:

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
   <value>master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
   <value>master:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
   <value>master:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>master:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
   <value>master:8033</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```